# How to debug Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP::TLS?

Tags: perl, email, smtp

I am developing an application to send emails through SMTP. I have a server, that supports both SMTP and SMTP::TLS.

Sending though SMTP works. Here is the code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Email::Sender::Simple qw(sendmail);
use Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP ();
use Email::Simple ();
use Email::Simple::Creator ();

my $smtpserver   = 'server.com';
my $smtpport     = 2525;
my $smtpuser     = 'test@server.com';
my $smtppassword = 'secret';

my $transport = Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP->new({
  host          => $smtpserver,
  port          => $smtpport,
  sasl_username => $smtpuser,
  sasl_password => $smtppassword,
});

my $email = Email::Simple->create(
  header => [
    To      => 'my-email@gmail.com',
    From    => $smtpuser,
    Subject => 'Hi!',
  ],
  body => "This is my message\n",
);

sendmail($email, { transport => $transport });
```

Sending through SMTP::TLS doesn't work.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Email::Sender::Simple qw(sendmail);
use Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP::TLS ();
use Email::Simple ();
use Email::Simple::Creator ();

my $smtpserver   = 'server.com';
my $smtpport     = 465;
my $smtpuser     = 'test@server.com';
my $smtppassword = 'secret';

my $transport = Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP::TLS->new({
  host     => $smtpserver,
  port     => $smtpport,
  username => $smtpuser,
  password => $smtppassword,
  debug    => 1,
});

my $email = Email::Simple->create(
  header => [
    To      => 'my-email@gmail.com',
    From    => $smtpuser,
    Subject => 'Hi!',
  ],
  body => "This is my TLS message\n",
);

sendmail($email, { transport => $transport });
```

How can I debug, what's going on? In [`Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP) I got debug messages, after adding `debug => 1`. But in [`SMTP::TLS`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP::TLS) I don't get it.

Currently TLS version just hangs.

Answer (score 1):

try with https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Sender::Transport::SMTPS

in 0.03 that I just shipped. I added debug => 1.

Comment: actually I just tried with the examples https://metacpan.org/source/FAYLAND/Email-Sender-Transport-SMTPS-0.03/xt/send.pl it works.

Answer (score 0):

In the [documentation](http://search.cpan.org/~fayland/Email-Sender-Transport-SMTP-TLS-0.15/lib/Email/Sender/Transport/SMTP/TLS.pm), the author appears to wrap the sendmail method in a try/catch like so:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Email::Sender::Simple qw(sendmail);
use Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP::TLS;
use Try::Tiny;


my $smtpserver   = 'server.com';
my $smtpport     = 2525;
my $smtpuser     = 'test@server.com';
my $smtppassword = 'secret';

my $transport = Email::Sender::Transport::SMTP::TLS->new({
    host     => $smtpserver,
    port     => $smtpport,
    username => $smtpuser,
    password => $smtppassword,
    debug    => 1,
});

my $email = Email::Simple->create(
  header => [
    To      => 'my-email@gmail.com',
    From    => $smtpuser,
    Subject => 'Hi!',
  ],
  body => "This is my TLS message\n",
);

try {
        sendmail($message, { transport => $transport });
    } catch {
        die "Error sending email: $_";
    };
```

Also, he admits that the module is in alpha phase and to use at your own risk.